# BackHandler not working in React-native Side menu Page

Tags: react-native, side-menu

I am working one sample project using `react-native!` in this project I used the `side menu component`, for navigation I used `react-native-router-flux`.

I am using a back handler not a navigation to main page. It's getting close the app.

Please give me your best suggestions on how to handle this issue.